# Check if user has Runkeeper using Facebook Connect

Tags: facebook

When a user signs up for Runkeeper using their Facebook User (Facebook Connect) they don't get a username.

So how can I use Facebook Connect to find out if a FB user has a Runkeeper account?

Thanks

Comment: I just want to clarify. I assume that `Runkeeper` is an `facebook app.` So what you want is to confirm if the user is already using your Runkeeper app?

Comment: I used Runkeeper Connect to solve this.